# Adding HMR for multiple HtmlWebpackPlugin outputs in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to add HMR to my existing project. So let's start with how the things are managed currently.

I have multiple HTML files that needs to be served at different routes. So for `/about` page, I have about.html that needs to be served, along with the whole react app javascript. So this is how my current code looks like:

In `webpack.config.js`, I'm using HtmlWebpackPlugin for adding title and js files with their chunkhash.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: `Welcome to my app`,
  template: './build/index.html',
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: `Welcome to my app`,
  filename: 'about.html',
  template: './build/about.html',
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: `Welcome to my app`,
  filename: 'base.html',
  template: './build/base.html',
}),
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
```

This is how "output" in webpack config looks like. I have publicPath set to '/'.

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/[name]-[hash].js',
  },
```

And this is how my server.js file looks like, where i'm using the webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware.

```
const compiler = require('webpack')(webpackConfig);
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  colors: true,
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  quiet: true,
  noInfo: true,
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr',
}));
```

And this is how i'm serving the HTML files:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html')));
app.get('/about', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../build/about.html')));
app.get('/status', (req, res) => res.send('Status OK'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../build/base.html')));
```

Now, When I open the `/` of the route, Everything works great along with HMR. But whenever I open `/about` or `/anything`, the about.html or base.html loads, but there's no app script added to that.

Why is it working for the index route and not other routes ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: could you show your webpack entry config?

Answer (score 0):

dev-Server don't write HTML on disk.
so it is not creating other HTML files and adding chunks to it.
for the index, I think it is using memory to serve HTML.

try using https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-harddisk-plugin
https://gist.github.com/ampedandwired/becbbcf91d7a353d6690